# chamar imagem através do id da resposta no formulário

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

tenho um formulário, onde a cada resposta o resultado é guardado no banco de dados e apresentado em uma tabela:

```
<td> <center> <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($row["data"])); ?> </center> </td>
<td> <center> <?php echo $row["nome"];?></center> </td>
<td> <center> <?php echo $row["img"];?></center> </td>
```

como faço para chamar uma determinada imagem pela resposta dada no formulário?

Exemplo: Usuário respondeu sim no formulário e na tabela aparece uma imagem x

Comment: Isso depende muito de como foi feito a estrutura do banco de dados, se tiver usado `BOLEAN` (True e False) pode usar isso de parametro no HTML gerado dinamicamente pelo PHP:



`<img src="<?php echo $variavel_do_resultado_do_db_referente_a_pergunta; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $variavel_do_resultado_do_db_referente_a_pergunta; ?>" />`

Mas sem conhecer o código ou a estrutura do DB sem chances de escrever um exemplo mais claro que este.

Comment: Seria uma especie de *quiz*?

Comment: correto, como se fosse um quiz

Comment: não estou utilizando BOLEAN, estou utilizando a estrutura básica nome: varchar, data:timestamp, etc

Comment: na tabela: <td> <center> <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($row["data"])); ?> </center> </td>
                    <td> <center> <?php echo $row["nome"];?></center> </td>

Answer (score 1):

consegui fazer a chamada, segue a maneira:`<?php if($row["nometabelaBD"] == 'SIM'){   echo "<img src=\"img.jpg\">";}`
bastou fazer um if ali e resolvi o problema, mas agradeço a todos pelos comentários

Answer (score 0):

Pelo **id** fica inviável, pois sendo que cada registro possui um **id**, se você tiver 200 registros, hipoteticamente teria que criar 200 imagens para cada um e criar mais imagens para os **id**s vindouros, o que torna isso inviável. Mas pelo teor da pergunta, creio que não seja essa a intenção (apenas o título supõe isso).

O que você pode fazer é criar uma imagem para cada tipo de resposta e subir para o servidor:

- **sim.png** e
- **nao.png**

Ao puxar os dados do banco, basta verificar que tipo de resposta foi dada e carregar a respectiva imagem. Seria algo assim:

```
<td> <center> <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($row["data"])); ?> </center> </td>
<td> <center> <?php echo $row["nome"];?></center> </td>
<td> <center> <img src="<?php echo $resposta;?>.png" /></center> </td>
```

Onde a variável `$resposta` deverá ter o valor de "**sim**" ou "**nao**" vindo do PHP de acordo com a resposta dada, e que irá completar o nome da imagem no HTML.